# JavaScript Equivalent to C# LINQ or another way to fetch data

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, linq

I have the JS array something like that

```
var arr = [{
   TimeEdit: "2020-10-29T10:45:00.21Z", 
   Date: "2020-10-29T00:00:00", 
   Parameters: [ { Id: 1, Value: 1}, { Id: 2, Value: 348 }]
   },{
   TimeEdit: "2020-10-29T10:43:52.22Z", 
   Date: "2020-10-29T00:00:00", 
   Parameters: [ { Id: 1, Value: 12}, { Id: 2, Value: 348 }]
   },{
   TimeEdit: "2020-10-30T10:47:12.33Z", 
   Date: "2020-10-30T00:00:00", 
   Parameters: [ { Id: 1, Value: 3}, { Id: 2, Value: 2 }]
}];
```

and I want to select from this array data with a unique "Date" sorted by "TimeEdit" so that at the output I can get this array

```
[{
   TimeEdit: "2020-10-29T10:45:00.21Z", 
   Date: "2020-10-29T00:00:00", 
   Parameters: [ { Id: 1, Value: 1}, { Id: 2, Value: 348 }]
   },{
   TimeEdit: "2020-10-30T10:47:12.33Z", 
   Date: "2020-10-30T00:00:00", 
   Parameters: [ { Id: 1, Value: 3}, { Id: 2, Value: 2 }]
}];
```

In C# code I would do something like that:

```
var dates = arr.Select(r => r.Date).Distinct().ToList();
foreach (var date in dates)
{
   WorkLog log = arr.Where(r => r.Datetime == date).OrderByDescending(r => r.TimeEdit).FirstOrDefault();
   //to do some stuff here
}
```

So what is the best way to do so in JS?

Comment: have you tried anything with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a number of built-in functions that help you in working with arrays in a linq-ish way. Functions like `map` (equivalent of `Select`) and `filter` (equivalent of `Where`) come to mind. Check out MDN for [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Even though these can be very useful, it can be useful to use another library for working with arrays or objects. From my experience [lodash](https://lodash.com/) is very handy for manipulating arrays. It has a `chain` method that you can use to express operations in a very linq-ish way.

```
const dates = _.chain(arr).map(r => r.Date).uniq().value();

dates.forEach(date => {
  const log = _.chain(arr)
    .filter(r => r.Datetime === date)
    .sortBy(r => r.TimeEdit)
    .reverse()
    .head();

  //to do some stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mimic the behaviour with some own function for grouping, ordering, sorting and getting the first item of each group. Fo binding all together, you need a pipe function as well.

```js
const
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    groupBy = key => array => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var fn = typeof key === 'function' ? key : o => o[key],
            temp = r.find(([p]) => fn(o) === fn(p));
        if (temp) temp.push(o);
        else r.push([o]);
        return r;
    }, []),
    order = (...keys) => array => array.sort((a, b) => {
        var result;
        keys.some(k => result = a[k] > b[k] || -(a[k] < b[k]));
        return result
    }),
    select = fn => array => array.map(fn),
    first = array => array[0],
    data = [{ TimeEdit: "2020-10-29T10:45:00.21Z", Date: "2020-10-29T00:00:00", Parameters: [{ Id: 1, Value: 1 }, { Id: 2, Value: 348 }] }, { TimeEdit: "2020-10-29T10:43:52.22Z", Date: "2020-10-29T00:00:00", Parameters: [{ Id: 1, Value: 12 }, { Id: 2, Value: 348 }] }, { TimeEdit: "2020-10-30T10:47:12.33Z", Date: "2020-10-30T00:00:00", Parameters: [{ Id: 1, Value: 3 }, { Id: 2, Value: 2 }] }],
    result = pipe(
        groupBy('Date'),
        select(
            pipe(
                order('TimeEdit'),
                first
            )
        )
    )(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```